# Functional Lifting in Optimisation - Reference Request

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convex-optimization

I'm looking to learn about the use of (functional) [lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_%28mathematics%29) applied to a non-convex optimisation problem to give a (larger) convex problem. Unfortunately, I'm having  a great deal of trouble finding suitable sources to learn from (largely because a Google search of 'functional lifting' returns mostly physical lifting ("bro, do you even lift?")!).

Any suitable papers, journals or lecture notes would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I strongly suspect that any of us would Google, too. However, I find that if I search for `"lifting" "convex" "optimization"`, including the quotes, I get targeted results. No idea if any of them are useful to you. That said, *this very post* is on the first page, which is not a good sign.

Comment: Ok yeah, thanks very much. Incidentally, what do the quotes do when only containing one word? Do they just require that that word is there?

Comment: Yes, that is what they do!

Comment: Excellent, thanks. One of the first ones on there looks quite helpful! :)

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what you mean. There is the standard reformulation lifting technique (RLT) typically used for bilinear/polynomial problem leading to large LPs. Googling on that leads to a wealth of material by, e.g., Sherali, Balas etc.

Then you have lifting to more exotic cones such as  semidefinite relaxation. Same thing there, google semidefinite relaxations and you will find loads of papers. The papers by Lasserre and Henrion might be a good start.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll look into that. Thanks especially for the specific mention at the end. :)

Comment: Can you give me the name of the paper by Lassere and Henrion ?

Comment: https://yalmip.github.io/reference/lassere2001/